# How to I add specific meta tags to panels pages?

Tags: 7, panels, meta-tags

I have panels pages, and I need to set specific meta tags per page.  The meta tags module lets you set up defaults, but I need specific tags per URL.

I can't seem to find this anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is now the [Meta tags: Panels](http://drupal.org/project/metatag_panels) module.
Works fine for me.

> This module extends the Meta tags module by adding support for meta tags configuration for panels pages.

Answer (score 2):

The sandbox [Panels meta](http://drupal.org/sandbox/Dustin/1210648) is the best option I have found so far. It supports  context substitutions so you could get the meta tags from fields in your entities or add it manually per Panels page.

Unfortunately the project is still a sandbox but hopefully we can help Dustin make it a full project by testing it etc.

Comment: I tried that module, but it doesn't really help.  You can't set the title tag.

Comment: Have a look at the Page title module, http://drupal.org/project/page_title

Comment: I did.  That one doesn't let you set specific titles per url.  I have a need to set specific and dynamic titles for panels.

Answer (score 1):

The [Modul Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) now comes with a submodul supporting customized meta tags for Panels.